# Using a number with mySQL IN() function

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble using mySQL IN() when using it with a number, rather than a field name.

My query is:

```
$query =    "select rental_id from {$this->table_name}
    where rental_id='$unit_id' AND '49' IN (specifications)";
```

The field specifications contains 20,10,49,22,18

An explanation states,

```
Note: #1003 /* select#1 */ select '270' AS `rental_id` from `mydatabase`.`rental_buildings` where 0
```

and shows and Extra of Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

If I remove the single quotes from the 49, I get

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '20,10,49,22,18'

Note: #1003 
    /* select#1 */ select '270' AS `rental_id`
    from `mydatabase`.`rental_buildings` 
    where (('270' = '270') and (49 = '20,10,49,22,18'))
```

This seems like it should be very straightforward, but I can't get it to work. I'd appreciate any guidance

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your query almost trivial. You need a one-to-many relationship for `IN` to work. Comma-separated data leads to huge performance problems since it must be decoded prior to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT rental_id FROM ...
  WHERE rental_id=? AND FIND_IN_SET(?, specifications)
```

Keep in mind this will be **exceptionally slow and extremely punishing on datasets of non-trivial size** as this must search through each field individually for all entries for that particular `rental_id`.

To fix this you need a proper relational table where your query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rental_id FROM specifications WHERE id=?
```

For that particular `specification_id`. This can be indexed and can be really fast.